# Reload log4j2 configuration on demand

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I have my log4j2.xml config file set to be checked every 30 seconds:

```
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    ...
</Configuration>
```

Is it possible to programmatically tell log4j2 to check for changes in the configuration instead of having a timeout?

**N.B.** I don't want to programmatically load the configuration specifying the config file, I just want to tell log4j2 to check the config file that has been loaded before as if the monitorInterval expired.

Thanks!

Comment: See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a3.6

Comment: @pringi I don't want to have log4j "watch" the config file... I just want to tell log4j when to check

Comment: Please find my comment from another https://stackoverflow.com/a/57215782/7532946

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It looks like I've found the solution:

```
((org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false)).reconfigure();
```

Does anyone see anything wrong/side-effects with this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I found this problemmatic when there are multiple logging contexts, like in OSGI or in web apps. In this case the code above reloads config in only one of the contexts

Comment: @plinyar what would the solution for OSGI/web-apps environment?

Comment: Sorry, @gaurav, already don't remember. Finally I preferred LogBack

Answer (score 5):

There is currently no clean way to do this.
It can be done with reflection. (Of course this may break if the implementation changes.)

UPDATE: this is wrong. There *is* a clean way, see jamp's answer below.

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext ctx = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);

org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.FileConfigurationMonitor mon = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.FileConfigurationMonitor) ctx.getConfiguration().getConfigurationMonitor();

// use reflection to get monitor's "nextCheck" field.
// set field accessible
// set field value to zero

mon.checkConfiguration();
```

Comment: Oh. There is no API for doing what you want to do. I honestly believe reflection is your only option with log4j-2.1. You can of course raise a feature request on the Jira issue tracker.

Comment: It looks like you're right... can't find anything... :(
Much to my regret, I'll accept it ;)

Comment: I take it back... I might have found a solution... I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

What about using `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator` ?

```java
   LoggerContext loggerContext = LoggerContext.getContext(false);
   final Configuration configuration = loggerContext.getConfiguration();
   Configurator.reconfigure(configuration);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.reconfigure()`?