# Log4j2 not creating subsequent logs files when using TestNg

Tags: selenium, testng, log4j2

I am using `eclipse` with testng and I am using `log4j2` for the logging. When I run the tests separately, a log file is created for each test and placed in a directory that has a `unique name` including the `datetime stamp`.

For example, when I run `test01`, a directory is created with the datetime and a log file is placed in that directory.

```
2016-12-10-21-16-04 tst_01
tst_01.log
```

When I run `test02` separately, a new directory is created based on the datetime and testname and a log file is added to the new directory.

```
2016-12-10-21-16-42 tst_02
tst_02.log
```

When I run the test suite using testng.  One log file is added to the directory of the first test, but there is `no log file that appears in the second directory`.

Also the log file that ends up in the directory of the first test contains `the log statements for the first test as well as the second test`.

Code Example:

```
public class TestLog{
  private static final Logger TestLog = LogManager.getLogger(TestLog.class.getName());
  public static void info(String message){
    TestLog.info(message);
  }
}
```

**Question:** How do I get a new log file to be created when running the tests using testng?

Comment: Please share some of your code.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the log4j2.xml file was not being updated for each test that was run.  The answer was to add the following to each test.

```
((org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false)).reconfigure();
```

This essentially reloads the log4j2.xml file thus picking up the new settings.

The answer was found at: http://https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216310/reload-log4j2-configuration-on-demand